# Some points regarding merge in hibernate documentation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Going through the Hibernate Documentation which covers the 4 basic points mentioned on JBoss site.
**merge()**

> **(1)**  if there is a **persistent instance** with the **same identifier**  currently 
>       associated with the session, copy the **state of the given object** onto 
>       the **persistent instance**
>
> **(2)** if there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session,
>       try to **load it** from the database, or **create a new persistent instance**
>
> **(3)** the **persistent instance** is **returned**
>
> **(4)** the **given instance** does not become associated with the session, it remains
>       **detached**

Consider the snippet:

```
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Employee employee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, 5);
        tx.commit();
        session.close(); // end of first session, employee is detached

        employee.getEmployeeId(); // The database identity is "5"
        employee.setFirstName("my new first description - Nauhkez");

        Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx2 = session2.beginTransaction();

        Employee employee2 = (Employee) session2.get(Employee.class, 5);
        Employee employee3 = (Employee) session2.merge(employee); // Success!

        System.out.println("Checking referential equality: "+(employee == employee3));

        tx2.commit();
        session2.close();
```

Is **employee** a persistent or detached object at this?

```
Employee employee3 = (Employee) session2.merge(employee); // Success!
```

Comment: The answer is in the question: *// end of first session, employee is detached* and *the given instance does not become associated with the session, it remains detached*.

Comment: @JB Nizet: you siad, "thethe given instance does not become associated with the session, it remains detached. Are you referring to employee as the given instance.

Comment: Yes. The *given* instance is the instance *given* as argument to `merge()`.

Comment: @JB Nizet: This is one of the things that confuses me a lot. Wasn't employee associated with a session by this line, session2.merge(employee)

Comment: No, since the documentatuion explicitely says: *the given instance does not become associated with the session, it remains detached*.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Can i then say when something like this is written session.save(enity), entity may or may not be session binded?

Comment: save() is different from merge(). It makes the given transient entity persistent, i.e. attached to the session.

Comment: Have a look at this article https://vladmihalcea.com/2014/07/30/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/ Btw. Vlad is a Hibernate commiter and one of the authors of the documentation.